# Batch variable from input not being updated

Tags: batch-file

I have the following snippet (some code omitted):

```
REM Verify destination_folders.
FOR %%f in (%destination_folders%) do (
    IF NOT EXIST %%f (
        echo(
        echo Destination folder %%f does not exist. Is version %version% correct? Please update the script with your required parameters.
        SET /p continue="Do you want to abort the operation? [Y/N]:"
        echo cont=%continue%

        IF %continue:~0,1%==y (
            goto :eof
        )

        IF %continue:~0,1%==Y (
            goto :eof
        )
    )
)
```

The issue is that the variable `continue` is not being assigned until after the script has been executed. For example, if `continue` was `N` from the the previous execution and then I input `Y` it will not update it, hence the echo after the assignment will output `cont=N` although it should be `cont=Y`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `help set` in a cmd console.  Skip to the section that begins, "Finally, support for delayed environment variable expansion has been added."  You need delayed expansion.  `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` somewhere, and use `!continue!` instead of `%continue%`.  The problem is that `%continue%` is expanded as the entire parenthetical code block is read for the first time, so it's treated as flat text by the time `for` performs its first loop.  `!continue!` retains its variability, and it's re-evaluated on each iteration.

Comment: You might also consider, instead of using `set /P`, use the `choice` command and `if not errorlevel 2 goto :EOF` to avoid having to use delayed expansion.

Comment: @rojo - why don't you submit your comment as an answer?

Comment: I must say I agree with npocmaka, submit them as answers so I can reward you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need delayed expansion. `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` somewhere, and use `!continue!` instead of `%continue%`. The problem is that `%continue%` is expanded as the entire parenthetical code block is read for the first time, so it's treated as flat text by the time for performs its first loop. `!continue!` retains its variability, and it's re-evaluated on each iteration.

You can also avoid the delayed expansion problem by using `choice` and `if errorlevel` like this:

```js
REM Verify destination_folders.
FOR %%f in (%destination_folders%) do (
    IF NOT EXIST "%%~f" (
        echo(
        echo Destination folder %%f does not exist. Is version %version% correct?
        echo Please update the script with your required parameters.

        choice /N /M "Do you want to abort the operation? [Y/N]: "
        if not errorlevel 2 goto :EOF
    )
)
```

---

To learn in greater detail about delayed expansion, read this portion of the `help set` documentation:

> Finally, support for delayed environment variable expansion has been added.  This support is always disabled by default, but may be enabled/disabled via the /V command line switch to CMD.EXE.  See CMD /?
>
> Delayed environment variable expansion is useful for getting around the limitations of the current expansion which happens when a line of text is read, not when it is executed.  The following example demonstrates the problem with immediate variable expansion:

```
set VAR=before
if "%VAR%" == "before" (
    set VAR=after
    if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
)
```

> would never display the message, since the %VAR% in BOTH IF statements is substituted when the first IF statement is read, since it logically includes the body of the IF, which is a compound statement.  So the IF inside the compound statement is really comparing "before" with "after" which will never be equal.  Similarly, the following example will not work as expected:

```
set LIST=
for %i in (*) do set LIST=%LIST% %i
echo %LIST%
```

> in that it will NOT build up a list of files in the current directory, but instead will just set the LIST variable to the last file found. Again, this is because the %LIST% is expanded just once when the FOR statement is read, and at that time the LIST variable is empty. So the actual FOR loop we are executing is:

```
for %i in (*) do set LIST= %i
```

> which just keeps setting LIST to the last file found.
>
> Delayed environment variable expansion allows you to use a different character (the exclamation mark) to expand environment variables at execution time.  If delayed variable expansion is enabled, the above examples could be written as follows to work as intended:

```
set VAR=before
if "%VAR%" == "before" (
    set VAR=after
    if "!VAR!" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
)

set LIST=
for %i in (*) do set LIST=!LIST! %i
echo %LIST%
```